# Did ubuntu really crashes hdd?

Tags: sound, hard-drive, hardware

After installing ubuntu my seagate barracuda (6yo), died in few days. That is why i had to buy new WD hdd-disk.
I installed ubuntu again and everything seems ok, but hdd works too loudly. When i used ktorrent, for example, it was loud clicking sound, during downloading file, with period ~0.5..1.5sec.
Next day i installed windows and i noticed that disk began to work VERY QUIET. No any clicks and ticks... Even when i downloaded something...

Now i'm afraid to install ubuntu again, because i think that it have serious problems with hdd usage.

Can anyone say something about this problem?

Comment: Sounds more like bad timing for the first drive. 6 years is a very long time for a hard drive to be in use. For the second one, I'd try an exchange. It sounds defective.

Comment: But this promblem exists only under ubuntu. 'Crystal disk info' says that disk is good condition. No reason to exchange it.

Comment: Well all I can say is I've never seen this issue. Maybe you have high RAM usage and Ubuntu is starting to use swap space?

Comment: No. I have 4gb RAM, monitor shows 0% swap usage. Its very strange....

Comment: Does it show 0% when the drive is making noise? 4GB isn't very little, but it isn't a lot either.

Comment: I dont remebmer exactly which moment i checked monitor data... But anyway even it swap-using noise, a can't explain why windows make it 
is much quieter. Disk - WD Red 1Tb. It is very quet in specifications. But only not with ubuntu :( :( :(

Comment: If Windows doesn't have swap set up, it won't use it.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - MS calls it a "page file"

Comment: @AndroidDev It doesn't matter what it's called. I'm pretty sure Windows doesn't have it set up by default though.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - It **does** have it set up by default. I know, because I recently reinstalled Windows 7 on a secondary HDD.